# Creating new roles Using Hasura metadata API

Tags: hasura, hasura-jwt

I am new to Hasura metadata API, Are there any REST API options to create roles via REST API. I am not asking about inherited roles. Inherited roles don't meet my requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use HASURA Metadata API to create a Permission and Pass the new role.

For example, let's say you're going to create a role called "MODERATOR" and give insert permission to the "comments" table.

you can use the [pg_insert_permission](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/api-reference/metadata-api/permission.html#pg-create-insert-permission) POST API with body:

```
{
"type": "pg_create_insert_permission",
"args": {
    "table": "comments",
    "source": "default",
    "role": "MODERATOR",
    "permission": {
        "check": {},
        "columns": ["comment"]
        }
    }
 }
```

This will create New Role "MODERATOR" in Hasura and also set the insert permission as well. Hope that answers your question.